# Четные числа Фибоначчи

Tags: php, алгоритм, числа-фибоначчи

Столкнулся с такой задачей:

> Каждый новый элемент последовательности Фибоначчи получается сложением предыдущих двух. Начиная с 1 и 2, получаем первые 10 элементов: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, … Найдите сумму всех четных элементов последовательности Фибоначчи, порядковый номер которых меньше A и верните из функции сумму всех ее цифр.

**Пример:** A = 10
**Ряд Фибоначчи:** 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89
**Четные элементы:** 2, 8, 34
**Их сумма:** 44, **а сумма всех ее чисел** - 8.

Показалось легко и начал решать таким способом:

```
<?php
  function solution($X) {
    $arr = array(1, 2);
    $sum = 0;
    $len = 0;

    for ($i = 2; $i <= $X; $i++) {
       array_push($arr, $arr[$i - 1] + $arr[$i - 2]);
       if ((($arr[$i - 1]) % 2) == 0 && ($i - 1) < $X) {
          $sum += $arr[$i - 1];
       }
    }

    while ($sum != 0 && $sum > 0) {
       $len += $sum % 10;
       $sum = intval($sum / 10);
    }

    return $len;
 }
 print solution(10);
```

Если при проверке указать 10(`solution(10)`), то ответ выдает верный, если указать число, которое больше 90, то ответ всегда равен 0.

Вопрос собственно такой. Где я ошибся?

Answer (score 6):

Эх не могу просто комментарий оставить. Но ошибки в алгоритме нет, просто есть ограничения. Операция деления по модулю `$a % $b` в php принимает целочисленные операнды, а если эта операция применяется к числам с плавающей точкой двойной точности, то эти числа предварительно преобразуются в целые числа (путем отбрасывания дробной части). Но у переменных типа int максимальное значение `9E18`.

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow

А при условии в '90' элементов `$sum = 1.2188452050948E+19`. И его приведение к типу `int` дает `0`.

Comment: Подскажи, как тогда мне избежать выхода за пределы `int`?

Comment: @Артем гугл "php длинная арифметика". Посмотрите и решите, а оно вам надо, ограничения в 90 не хватает. И кстати совершенно не понял зачем у вас в алгоритме используется массив. достаточно хранить только 2 последних числа ...

Comment: @Mike когда я изучал алгоритмы, то при нахождении чисел Фибоначчи рекомендовали использовать массив. В задачи, которую я нашел на сайте [certification.mail.ru](https://certification.mail.ru/lc/), в качестве проверки результата брали 30000.

Comment: @Артем давайте грубо вычислим, длина 30.000 числа будет 10.000 десятичных знаков (ооочень грубо через 2^N). Сложение делается за длину числа, всегда 30.000 сложений, умножить на 10.000 длину итого 300 миллионов. На любом компилируемом языке я уверен что успеет. На php не знаю, активно не пользовался. Но думаю более чем реально,